# Determining package manager by file existence

Tags: linux

I need to determine what package manager a given system uses, but am limited to checking file existence. I am looking for a file that does (to some degree) prove that the distribution at hand has an RPM database or uses apt/debs . I immediately think of /etc/apt/sources.list for example. I know I can't get %100 of all cases, but I'd like to get as close as possible for the major distros (e.g. Debian based, Red Hat based, etc..)

Thank you!

Comment: For Debian systems you would probably be better off looking at `/var/lib/dpkg/`.  Having APT configured is not an absolute requirement.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you, that's a good start. What about for RPMs? Where are they typically kept?

Answer (score 0):

For RPM, you'd have /usr/lib/rpm.

Or you could directly check for the core executable: /bin/rpm (dunno Debianites). Probably the best bet, is to look for the basic executable. Should help for other, more exotic, package management systems too.

BTW, what are you trying to do? And why the strange restriction on "only check for file existence"?